# Topological degree

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I need help for this exercice

1)Let $\Omega$ be an open and bounded set from $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f\in C(\overline{\Omega})$
,we suppose that there exists
$x_0 \in \Omega$ such that :if for $x\in  \partial \Omega$
$f(x) − x_0 = \lambda (x − x_0)$  then $\lambda \leq1$.
 Show that f has a fixed point in $\overline{\Omega}$.

Comment: what do you mean by $f(x)-x_0 = \lambda(x-x_0)$? I suppose that it is $|f(x)-f(x_0) |= \lambda\|(x-x_0)\|$

Comment: no, it is written like that. in fact it looks like Exercise 9 of the book
"topological degree theory and applications"

Comment: so $f:\overline{\Omega}\rightarrow\overline{\Omega}$?

Comment: i don't know , i think that it is from $\overline\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ !

Comment: 1) Put that proposition in your post to show you've worked on the problem before asking the question. This is why you're getting downvotes. 2) Everybody needs help with things. Don't be pushy.r

Comment: i don't understand why they put -1 ?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ has a fixed point on the boundary, we are done. Suppose not.

We then start with the following observation:
\begin{equation} \tag{$*$}
f(x)-x_0 \ne \frac 1t (x-x_0)
\end{equation}
for all $t \in (0,1)$ and for all $x \in \partial \Omega$
(for otherwise, according to the condition, we get
that $1 < \displaystyle \frac 1t \leqslant 1$ which is impossible).

Let $t \in [0,1]$ and let
$$
g_t(x)=x-t(f(x)-x_0).
$$
Equivalently, Eq. $(*)$ says that
$$
x_0 \not \in g_t( \partial \Omega),
$$
and so $x_0$ is a "legitimate" point for
calculation of
$$
\mathrm{deg}(g_t,\Omega,x_0)
$$
for all $t \in (0,1).$

Now since $f$ has no fixed points on the boundary, we also have that
$$
x_0 \not\in g_1(\partial \Omega),
$$
and since $x_0 \not\in \partial \Omega,$ we have that
$$
x_0 \not\in g_0(\partial \Omega). 
$$
Thus by Theorem 1.2.6 from the book you have quoted
above (the "homotopy" part),
$$
\mathrm{deg}(g_t,\Omega,x_0)=\mathrm{deg}(g_0,\Omega,x_0)=\mathrm{deg}(\mathrm{id},\Omega,x_0)=1.
$$
for all $t \in [0,1]$ (the last equality--again the aforementioned theorem, the "solvability" part). Hence $\mathrm{deg}(g_1,\Omega,x_0)=1,$ and there is a point $x \in \Omega$
with 
$$
g_1(x)=x_0 \iff x-f(x)+x_0=x_0 \iff f(x)=x.
$$

Comment: thank you , thank you, i just have a small question : i don't understand " if f has a fixed point in the boundary then we are done" . if $x \in \partial\Omega, f(x)=x$?

Comment: Yes. We are to find a fixed point of $f$ in $\overline \Omega=\Omega \sqcup \partial \Omega.$ If there is one in the boundary, it is OK. If not, we have to find a fixed point in $\Omega$ itself. To feel things better, try to rewrite in a detailed way the proof of Th. 1.2.7 from your book. Take my answer above as an example.